# Helicopters with landing skids, no wheels; How are they taken in and out of a hangar?

Tags: helicopter, landing-gear, ground-operations

I'm sure many helicopters also need/use Hangars frequently. How do you take them to a hangar and take them out of it without wheels?

Specially when they have to be taken indoors for some maintenance work on them. Are there any special forklifts/carts used for ground handling of helicopters that do not use wheels and need to be moved without actually flying?

Comment: [They are placed on movable skids or carts](https://www.google.com/search?q=helicopter+cart&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1662&bih=846&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr8Zb4mbTMAhXLOSYKHT9HDhkQsAQIJw), or have wheels that can be attached to the skids so they can be rolled.

Comment: Silly me, that term looks like such an easy find when i think of it now. Thanks!

Comment: @RonBeyer: You grabbed a [strange thing](https://highheelsandalmondfields.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/img_1468.jpg) with your query! Seems to be supersonic, re. the cooled blades

Comment: @mins Looks like parking control is trying a new tactic

Comment: [Many have wheels that attach to the skids](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=helicopter+skid+wheels&biw=1365&bih=679&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh47j7pLTMAhVKOBQKHeIRD2wQ_AUIBygC)

Comment: @simon how to attach them when needed? I think that would require some sort of jack right?

Comment: @mins I saw that and immediately thought "I want one"... Guess I'll never grow up.

Comment: @HankyPanky Here is a video that shows how wheels can be attached: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2mUQ7Oonhs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, you put wheels on the skid and tow them.

In some cases, towing wheels are attached to the skids (which usually have sleeves in them for mounting), and a tow bar is attached to the front (one or two sets of wheels may be attached to the skids), which is then towed by a vehicle.

[image: Helicopter towing]

Image from [incrediblediary.com](http://www.incrediblediary.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/helicopter_WId4e_6648.jpg)

There are also specialised tow carts available for helicopters, which basically grip the skids (usually in a couple of places on either side) and lift them up, after which the helicopter can be moved by the operator by controlling the cart.

[image: Helicopter cart]

Image from [hasmak.com](http://www.hasmak.com.tr/yeni/dosyalar/images/v900_bell206.jpg)